# Browser-side JS: How to export functions imported in ESM the conventional way

Tags: javascript, browser, module, export, es6-modules

My main .html file:

```html
<head>
    <script src="esm.js" type="module"></script>
    <script>
       // Test imported stuff inside esm.js
       console.log(get,set); // <-- Error, not defined
    </script>
</head>
```

The esm.js file:

```js
// ES module imports
import {get,set} from "https://unpkg.com/idb-keyval@5.0.2/dist/esm/index.js";

export get;
export set;
```

The 2 export lines in esm.js doesn't work, I could change them to:

```
window.get = get;
window.set = set;
```

But setting properties for 'window' object seems unconventional in a module as it should be done by 'export' keyword, how to use 'export' keyword there instead?

Comment: Your'e supposed to use ESM modules in other ESM modules. If you want to import them in a regular `script` tag you have to attach them to `window`, or use the UMD packaged version of the script you're importing

Comment: seems attaching them to `window` the only way?

Comment: If you import as ESM yes it's the only way